# Как снизить нагрузку на ЦП?

Tags: windows, c++

Здравствуйте, создал программу и хочу, чтобы она постоянно считывала из системы время и через некоторое время генерировала событие. Программа вроде получилась. Но почему процессор чуть ли не на 40% нагружен из-за нее?

```
#include <windows.h> // подключаем заголовочный файл Windows
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void func()
{}

INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
                   INT nCmdShow)
{

    int s2 = 0;
    int min = 0;
    while (1) {

    int s1 = (clock() / 1000) % 60;

    if (s1 == 59) {
        min++;
    }
    if (min == 1) 
    {
        min = 0;
        func();
    }
    // cout << s1 << "\r";

    }
}
```

В чем ошибка? И можете параллельно подсказать, как, чем организовывается перехват "горячей комбинации клавиш"?

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно попробовать внутри цикла сделать задержку, хотя бы Sleep(10);

Comment: Ого, Sleep сильно помог, спасибо. Еще есть варианты?

Comment: А почему Вы решили что здесь есть ошибка? Вполне себе нормальное поведение, программа ведь постоянно работает, занимает процессорное время.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант первый, совсем в лоб. Так как мы знаем, когда должен сработать таймер, то можно sleep вначале поставить на достаточно большой отрезок времени, приблизительно за несколько минут до предполагаемой даты срабатывания. Почему чуточку раньше? просто никто не гарантирует, что sleep отработает строго заданное время (угадать точное время можно будет  только в qnx).

Вариант два. Более реальный и красивый. С помощью функции SetTimer заводим таймер на нужное время. Одним с параметром функция требует функцию-коллбек. Ее то и вызовет система, когда придет время. Можно выставить на срабатывание каждую минуту и, думаю, для Ваших целей было бы предостаточно.

Вариант три. Использовать системный планировщик. В этом случае, даже если система будет перегружена, код все равно сработает (если конечно он был корректно добавлен и не был удален/заблокирован третьей стороной). Но это уже не такая и тривиальная задача.

Comment: Некоторая проблема использования SetTimer в том, что программе придется в ожидании срабатывания таймера что-то делать. Если делать нечего - хотя бы крутить вечный цикл. На мой взгляд в этом случае использование стандартного механизма ожидаемого таймера (Waitable Timer) логичнее

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart=-10000000;

    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, TEXT("WaitableTimer"));
    if (NULL == hTimer) return 1;

    for ( int t = 0; ; t++ ) {
        if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0)) break;

        if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            printf("\r%d", t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```